# Regex to exclude from second capture group if matches certain criteria

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

My regex so far is:

```
^(UCX_|UBX_|USP_)([A-Za-z0-9]\w+)(_\d+)?$
```

When I test the string:

```
UCX_1maxi_holiday2_blah_343
```

It correctly tests true however my last capture group will never be reached because it matches the second group also.
i.e. if the last underscore demarcated section is all numbers I want that section in the third capture group not the second. Else I want it in the second group.

I've thought of lookaheads and -behinds and I don't think they will work for this but I could be surprised.

I could do a separate test to check the end of the string alone, then split the strings as I need but intellectual curiosity.

I'm wondering if there is a way to amend the second capture group to stop it from clobbering the end if it's all numbers

Anyone's got some Regex JiuJitsu for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the second capture to non-greedy, you'll get what you want.
Use:

```
^(UCX_|UBX_|USP_)([A-Za-z0-9]\w+?)(_\d+)?$
```

Comment: That works. My initial understanding of nongreedy needs some education. So non greedy would pass on eating if it knows the next pattern will take it?

Comment: Generally, yes.  Greedy expressions are usually faster, since non-greedy matches will need to look ahead or backtrack (in order to `know` what it needs to leave for the next part of the pattern); in a great many cases, the speed difference never matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify doing that:

```
^(UCX_|UBX_|USP_)(\w+?)(_\d+)?$
```

> `\w`  character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _
>   (underscore) character.

Comment: Thanks Marcel but this would require the group of numbers at the end and I'm trying to make it optional

Comment: Another regex variation: [`^(U(?:[BC]X|SP)_)((?!_)\w+?)(_\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/EdF7X2/1)

Comment: also @MarcelJacquesMachado [A-Za-z0-9]\w+?   the class before the /w is there because a starting underscore for that capture group is invalid.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Interesting alternative.